# $P+Q-PQ$ is a projection if and only if $PQ=QP$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space and $P,Q:\mathcal H \to \mathcal H$ are projections. I want to show that $P+Q-PQ$ is a projection if and only if $PQ=QP$. If $PQ=QP$ clearly $P+Q-PQ$ is a projection. But when $P+Q-PQ$ is a projection, how I can show that $PQ=QP$? I tried to use $$(P+Q-PQ)^2=P+Q-PQ$$ And I got: $$QP-QPQ-PQP+(PQ)^2=0$$ And from here: $$(Q-PQ)(P-PQ)=0$$ Can somebody give me a hint? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are $P,Q$ orthogonal projections?

Comment: @copper.hat: The question com's from "Wavelet Transforms and their applications" by Debnath in chapter $2$ Exercise $81$ and the author didn't said anything about orthogonality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement Math1000's answer, the path of working with the equality $(P+Q-PQ)^2=P+Q-PQ$ cannot lead to a proof (i.e., the argument does not work for idempotents alone). Let 
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $PQ=Q$, $QP=P$, and $$P+Q-PQ=P=(P+Q-PQ)^2.$$

Answer (score 4):

If $P+Q-PQ$ is a projection, then 
\begin{align}
P+Q-PQ &= (P+Q-PQ)^*\\
&= P^* + Q^* - (PQ)^*\\
&= P^* + Q^* - Q^*P^*\\
&= P + Q - QP,
\end{align}
from which it follows that $PQ=QP$.

Comment: This is only true if the projection is an orthogonal projection. For example, $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a projection, but not orthogonal.

Comment: @copper.hat Correct, an idempotent operator is self-adjoint iff it is an orthogonal projection. I believe this extra condition is necessary for the claim to be true, however.

Comment: @copper.hat that extra claim is implicitly true. An idempotent $P$ is a projection if and only if it is an orthogonal projection onto ran $P$ – see Conway's functional analysis textbook chapter 2 Proposition 3.3

Comment: @SamBlattner: I don't have Conway's book handy to check the statement, but the $P$ is my example about is a projection ($P^2=P$) but not an orthogonal one.